# VBScript Regular Expression to find Triple Pipes(|),double ,single

Tags: regex, vb.net, vbscript

Need help building a VBScript regex that checks for Triple (|||) and || and | and gives output as 
For Example:-

```
Contacts ||| ||Position: |PosH | |Pos Cust ||Name: |Name H | |Name Cust || 

a1:-Contacts,a2:||Position: |PosH | |Pos Cust ||Name: |Name H | |Name Cust || 
b1:-Position:, b2:-Name:
c1:PosH ,c2: ,c3:Pos Cust
```

Comment: So where is it that you need help with?

Comment: I need the output to display as.In one string[] all within triple(|||)second string with (||) and third with (|).I need a Regex .I am now using the Mid and Instr functions which are not helping me .

Comment: you could do three splits a la Ekkehard Horner's answer: one with three, one with two, and one with one pipe character(s) as a delimiter. After each split, strip all pipes from the result array elems, and ignore all empty array elems. This should deliver what you need. Alternatively, you could show the code that does not work for you, and we´ll see.

Comment: If you really want to use a regex, please give it a try yourself, and post your code here. It is much more productive for us all (including you) to help you to improve your own solution than just spitting out a brand new one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Split():

```
>> s = "Contacts ||| ||Position: |PosH | |Pos Cust ||Name: |Name H | |Name Cust ||"
>> a = Split(s, "|")
>> For i = 0 To UBound(a)
>>     WScript.Echo i, """" & a(i) & """"
>> Next
>>
0 "Contacts "
1 ""
2 ""
3 " "
4 ""
5 "Position: "
6 "PosH "
7 " "
8 "Pos Cust "
9 ""
10 "Name: "
11 "Name H "
12 " "
13 "Name Cust "
14 ""
15 ""
>> WScript.Echo "a1", """" & a(0) & """"
>> WScript.Echo "c3", """" & a(8) & """"
>>
a1 "Contacts "
c3 "Pos Cust "
>>
```

(and throw in some Trim()s)

Comment: @Horner I need output like a1=Contacts a2=||Position: |PosH | |Pos Cust ||Name: |Name H | |Name Cust

Comment: +1 for being to lazy to create a script, and using the direct command prompt :)